# Which is the best structure for an Android SVN project?

Tags: android, svn

Which is the better structure for an SVN repository that will hold a single Android project (and why)?

```
http://myserver/svn
    /trunk
        /MyProject
            /src
            /res
            /assets
    /branches
    /tags
```

or

```
http://myserver/svn
    /trunk
        /src
        /res
        /assets
    /branches
    /tags
```

**Basically I want to know if the project root folder should be explicitly named in the hierarchy.** The repository will only hold one project but it will have many branches and tags. I'm using Eclipse with an SVN plug-in.

Thanks,

Barry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have it like this:

```
http://myserver/svn
    MyProject1
        /trunk
            /src
            /res (external)
            /assets
        /branches
        /tags
    MyProject2
       /trunk
           /src
           /res (external)
           /assets
       /branches
       /tags
    resources
```

Haven't done much of Android development, but stuff like resources I usually keep outside the main source structure and make use of `svn:externals` to link think and potentially use them across various projects

Answer (score 5):

What I am generally doing *(both for android and other technologies such as PHP -- and for SVN and other source control software such as Bazaar or Git)*, is something like this :

```
http://myserver/svn
    /MyProject
        /trunk
            /sources
                /src
                /res
                /assets
            /ressources
                => Here, I can put text files, documentation, ...
                that is really part of the projet -- but not part of the application
        /branches
        /tags
```

So, pretty close to your first idea, except :

- I can have more than one project on my SVN server,
- Each projet has its own trunk/branches/tags
- In each project, I have the source code ; and some other directories that are not part of the application, but related-enough to be in the SVN of the project